# Alt HMC in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to remap a function key like F4 to do an ALT then press H + M + C.
Tried reading the docs but was not successful in getting my answer.

I actually thought this may work but it's not.

> F4::!hmc

Comment: Is that for excel unmerge?

Comment: Yes, pretty awesome once I figure this out.

Comment: Most office products have built in macros of custom hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

That was probably working, but AutoHotkey runs too fast for most applications to pick up on the macros. It looks like you want to manipulate Word or some sort of ribbon menu. Try this:

```
SetKeyDelay, 50 ; Increase this to increase the delay
F4::!mhc
```

You could also try switch our your ! for {Alt} and see if you get any improvements there. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I am actually getting  
Error: This line does not contain a recognized action. Tried using {Alt} as well no luck. SetKeyDelay sure is working

Comment: Can you pot your script?

Comment: > F4::!hmc - this is it nothing else

Comment: That carrot on the left isn't in your code, right? It should just be: F4!hmc which works perfect for me.

Comment: Just this F4::!hmc nothing else. I was actually trying to put it in block quote but i guess it wont work on comments.